# Log file specified by gemfire.log-file never gets created

Tags: gemfire, geode

I have a web application hosted in Tomcat that uses a Geode cache but I cannot get Geode to produce a log file. The cache and properties, including the log-file property, are created programmatically. I see some Geode logging in the Tomcat stdout and it seems to confirm the log-file property has been set:

```
....
13:30:43,149 | INFO  | [LoggingSession] | Startup Configuration:
### GemFire Properties defined with system property ###
conserve-sockets=false
### GemFire Properties defined with api ###
....
log-disk-space-limit=0
log-file=/local/install/user1/config/Lev1/Web/WebAppServer/Server1_1/logs/gemfire.log
log-file-size-limit=0
log-level=config
....
```

However, the file specified never gets created.

I have tried setting the file permissions to 777 on that directory, as well as setting the log-level to 'fine' but neither made a difference. The Geode output only shows up in the stdout, which I believe is the default.

Why isn't the log file specified by the log-file property getting created?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you need to follow [these instructions](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/115/tools_modules/http_session_mgmt/tomcat_changing_gf_default_cfg.html) in order to change logging settings for the sessions module.

Comment: @JuanRamos I believe those instructions are specific to the Geode HTTP Module, which we aren't using.

Comment: I misread and thought you were referring to the Tomcat Session Module logging, not Geode itself for an application running within Tomcat, apologies. Is this plain Geode or Spring Boot Data Geode?

Comment: No worries, we are using plain Geode.

Comment: I was able to get a log file to appear with `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-jdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -server -Dgemfire.enable-cluster-configuration=true -Dgemfire.load-cluster-configuration-from-dir=false -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5006 -Dgemfire.member-timeout=600000 -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806 -Dgemfire.log-file=myLogFile.log com.vmware.gemfire.bootstrap.LocatorLauncher start locator --port=10334` what are you using to launch GemFire?